# How could someone whose trades are being copied be liable to the person who is doing the copying?

Tags: contract-law, theft, cryptocurrency

[It is reported](https://web3isgoinggreat.com/?id=nft-copytrader-tricked) that someone was copying the trades of a noted NFT trader.  This noted NFT trader profited from this by making an inflated bids on one of his own NFTs, and when the copycat replicated the trades on other NFTs they were purchased for ~10 times the usual rate.

[The copycat (ThinkingETH) has since described](https://twitter.com/ThinkingETH/status/1687888745465536513) the loss as "stolen funds", and [someone said](https://twitter.com/lex_node/status/1687916676380033025?s=20):

> I unironically think @ThinkingETH might have good legal claims to get their ETH back from the bot 'trick' if they hire a skilled litigator. Legally the issues are a bit more nuanced than they might be normatively from the standpoint of cryptotwitter.

Is there a case here?  Is there some nuanced issues that could mean that the seller is responsible for the seller to have "stolen" from the buyer?  Is there a civil case to be made that the funds should be returned?  Any jurisdiction would be interesting, as it seems to matter little where these events occur.

Comment: I don't know for sure  but would the [tag:insider-trading] tag be appropriate here?

Comment: @Rick This falls short of insider trading. The NFT trader simply took advantage of a pattern he noticed: other's propensity to replicate trades (or bids) *regardless of* the price.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I don't know for sure, but could there some breach of the selling platform's T&Cs for [shill bbidding](https://www.claims.co.uk/knowledge-base/consumer-law/shill-bidding)? -(According to that link it's actually unlawful in the UK)

Comment: @Rick NFTs are not stocks, certificates, or currency and often unregulated.

Comment: Potentially related: (https://law.stackexchange.com/q/5893/35069)

Comment: @Rick It would be interesting to see the applicable statutory definition of shill bidding. But the pattern of *blindly* copying that agent's trades suggests that the price was *de facto* irrelevant to the copycat.

Comment: Let’s change it a bit: The trader is annoyed by the copycat, and he is rich. So he buys an NFT for $10,000 that is worth $1,000, losing $9,000, waiting for the copycat to copy him and lose money as well. The copycat doesn’t care about values, he just copies the traders actions.

Answer (score 1):

### This type of fraud is called [shill bidding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shill#Auctions)

Unless the rules of the auction allow it, a vendor is not permitted to bid on their own item. Even when they are, such vendor bids may be disclosed.

The relevant laws date from well before the rise of online auctions but they are just as applicable. There have been successful prosecutions to my knowledge, including jail time, in the [USA](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2006/aug/02/art.crime) and the [UK](https://www.pinsentmasons.com/out-law/news/ebay-shill-bidder-fined-3500). A quick Google search shows these are not unique.

A victim of such a fraud can seek restitution through a civil claim.

Comment: Does the fact that his inflated bid was the winning bid (that is, he didn't bid on his own product, he *bought* it) make any difference?

Comment: @RyanJensen: Good question. I sell one expensive computer on eBay. I put in a high bid to convince others that the computer is very valuable, and to make sure they cannot get it cheap. That's shill bidding. Now I sell two expensive computers on eBay. I buy one with a very high bid but don't touch the second one.